# Specialization after instantiation error is not showing un-defined error

Tags: c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have experienced some issues with templates and their behaviour recently in our codebase which is pretty big. It's rather fascinating how simple-to-understand level-1 templates, become more complex as code size increases.

To reproduce one such instance:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int func2();

// uncommenting this make this code work
// template <>
// int func2<int>();

int func1()
{
    int val = func2<int>();
    return val;
}

template <>
int func2<int>()
{
    return 20;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func1() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the compile error: specialization after instantiation at line 17. https://godbolt.org/z/sbqoK5Yvd

I think it would be really helpful if the compiler mentioned exactly where and what it had instantiated the template, in a large code-base it gets confusing.

Afaik, the compiler instantiates the definition of a class/function/variable when it encounters it's first usage. But looking at my code, I never defined `func2<T>`. Why didn't it report `func2<int>()` definition not found, when instantiating `func2<int>` at its usage in func1? I never defined `func2<T>`. Why does it go ahead, and checks ok-wow we found a specialization for an instantiated template, reports one error but forgets about un-defined error?

A better version of my doubt would be, how does the instantiation looks like, for this example? My naive brain would think - it would be a template instantiation for the declaration like:

```
// compiler 
template <>
int func2<int>();

//and thus, using func2<int> should report un-defined
```

Is my understanding incorrect?

A good resource on templates at intermediate level, will be really helpful and definitely a bonus for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler reaches

```
int val = func2<int>();
```

it'll "instantiate" the only function template prototype it's seen so far:

```
template <typename T>
int func2();
```

You later provide a specialization, but it's too late. It has used the primary template to get a prototype for `int func2<int>()` already.

> Why didn't it report `func2<int>()` definition not found, when instantiating `func2<int>` at its usage in `func1`?

It had no reason. The primary template provided the `int func2<int>()` prototype it needed to continue.

Comment: So you mean it has not instantiated the definition, but the prototype? And it shows error on specialization on the *prototype-instantiation*?

Comment: @Akash Yes, take away the specialization and you should get a link error (since the promise made by providing a prototype isn't fulfilled).

Comment: Ok, then I have a doubt -  "The primary template provided the int func2<int>() prototype it needed to continue". Compiler ideally can't continue since the prototype isn't defined, and its being used where it got instantiated, right?

Comment: @Akash I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean. The prototype is just a promise that there will be a definition later, somewhere. The prototype will make it pass the compilation stage without the actual definition, but linking will fail if no definition is provided.

Comment: Nope, sorry, I forgot accepting the answer. Thank you